# How to make Reverse SSH Tunnels secure

Tags: security, authentication, ssh, reverse, tunnel

I am in the process of creating a script (lives on computer B) that initiates an ssh tunnel to my computer (computer A). Currently, the script on computer B takes in parameters like IP, port, and whatever else is required to start the ssh tunnel, including the password.

So I use an expect/send script to input the password. However, this is very insecure. So my question is, how can I make this script/process more secure? Are public keys the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the reason public/private keys exist.